# regex: Insert newline in html editor

Tags: regex, newline

If I have some html in my editor like this:

```
<p>Some code here.</p></This needs to be on a new line!>
```

How do I get the last tag on a new line in the actual editor (not the output)?

Comment: You want the p tag to be in a new line

Comment: No, I want the "</This...!>" to be on a new line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to put the last closing tag on a new line:

**Pattern:**

```
(</[a-zA-Z]+>)$
```

**Replace Pattern:**

```
\r\n\1
```

**Update:**

Exact match:

```
(</This needs to be on a new line!>)$
```

Comment: Before I make a mistake, how can I specify the exact characters of the closing tag...(</[This needs to be on a new line!>]>) ?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that:

```
 sed -i 's|\(.*p>\)\(</This.*\)|\1\n\2|g' <your files>

s         // substitute
|         // begin search
\(        // begin group 1
.*p>      // search greedy until 'p>' found
\)        // end group 1
\(        // begin group 2
</This.*  // search for '</This' then be greedy until the end 
\)        // end group 2
|         // begin replace
\1        // insert group 1
\n        // insert new line character '\n'
\2        // insert group 2
|         // end replace
g         // global replace for substitute
```